# Network Device Down Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless

When I boot up my Ubuntu pc wifi works and then it randomly stops working and when i do `ip link`
it says the device is down. If you have any tips on how to fix this please reply.

[ip link command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsNj0.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick restart should correct any potential issues. If the problems persists feel free to reply.

```
sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```